# Что лучше использовать для получения текущего урла?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

лучше получать путь при помощи `window.location.pathname` или обернуть компонент в `withRouter` и получать путь из `props`? (для разных проверок)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначно, я бы рекомендовал использовать `withRouter`. Вы же используете `React`, так используйте его вспомогательные и удобные средства. Думаю, тут выбор очевиден.

Сначала импортируем его в нашем компоненте:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

и оборачиваем в `withRouter` при экспорте

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

А затем у нас в пропсах есть все, что нам нужно, к примеру `this.props.history` или `this.props.location` или `this.props.match`. Тем более, что вы хотите его использовать для разных проверок. В дальнейшем использовании окажется очень полезным.

Ссылка на документацию:

- [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)
- [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)
- [`location`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md)
- [`match`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md)